Need a regex for removing double quotes from a string
So I have a string:
{"age":{"type":"Number","max":100,"default":"() => 0"},"created_at":{"type":"String","default":"() => moment().format(\"YY/MM/DD\")"}

I need to remove the outer double quotes from the values where the key is default. So the above string would become:
{"age":{"type":"Number","max":100,"default":() => 0},"created_at":{"type":"String","default":() => moment().format(\"YY/MM/DD\")}

I am using sed to do this right now, and this is the latest command I've tried:
sed -r 's/"(default)":"([^"]*)"/\\1: \\2/g'
The problem occurs at "() => moment().format(\"YY/MM/DD\")", the regex matches until the first \".
I'd really appreciate a regex that can solve this problem. It doesn't have to be done in a single step, I can run multiple commands in succession as long as I can successfully remove the outer double quotes.
It also doesn't have to be a sed command, it can be done through file manipulation as well, as long as the code is valid in javascript

You always have format in the strings?

It does not answer your question regarding the regex, but it probably would be more reliable to parse the JSON and then create a custom serializer/stringifier.

It sounds like you want to match escaped quotes inside. Also keep the quotes for the key? Try something like ("default"):"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"


It's best to parse, if possible, as commented.

If there is no option, it's best to write algorithms to handle this problem.



Pattern

You can replace "default"\s*:\s*"?\s*((?:[^"\r\n]*(?:\.format[^)]*[^"'\r\n]*)?))\s*"?\s* with "default":$1.

Note that this pattern will fail in many cases.


const regex =
  /"default"\s*:\s*"?\s*((?:[^"\r\n]*(?:\.format[^)]*[^"'\r\n]*)?))\s*"?\s*/gm;

const str = `{"age":{"type":"Number","max":100,"default":"() => 0"},"created_at":{"type":"String","default":"() => moment().format(\"YY/MM/DD\")"}
{"age":{"type":"Number","max":100,"default":() => 0},"created_at":{"type":"String","default":() => moment().format(\"YY/MM/DD\")}
{"type":"String","default":() => moment().someotherfunction())}
{"type":"String","default":"() => moment().someotherfunction())"}`;
const subst = `"default":$1`;
console.log(str.replace(regex, subst));

Prints
{"age":{"type":"Number","max":100,"default":() => 0},"created_at":{"type":"String","default":() => moment().format(YY/MM/DD")"}
{"age":{"type":"Number","max":100,"default":() => 0},created_at":{"type":"String","default":() => moment().format(YY/MM/DD")}
{"type":"String","default":() => moment().someotherfunction())}{"type":"String","default":() => moment().someotherfunction())}


